# cookie lax append issue

Tags: cookie, magento2.4.2

on magento 2.4.2 upgrade

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'cart' on string '{"messages":1613612384,"company":1613612384,"customer":1613612384,"compare-products":1613612384,"requisition":1613612384,"last-ordered-items":1613612384,"cart":1613612384,"directory-data":1613612384,"captcha":1613612384,"wishlist":1613612384,"company_authorization":1613612384,"negotiable_quote":1613612384,"instant-purchase":1613612384,"loggedAsCustomer":1613612384,"multiplewishlist":1613612384,"purchase_order":1613612384,"persistent":1613612384,"review":1613612384,"recently_viewed_product":1613612384,"recently_compared_product":1613612384,"product_data_storage":1613612384,"paypal-billing-agreement":1613612384}laxlaxlaxlaxlaxlax'`

Answer (score 0):

Try go to:

> Magento 2 admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default
> Cookie Settings

and set a value for "**Cookie Domain**" option. Besicaly enter your domain name withotu http or https and slashes. e.g.: myshop.com.

Save this setting and flush the Magento cache. Refresh the page.

This solved the issue for me. If it does not work for you, try to wait, visit a few pages. If still does not work then...

As another solution (please use it at your own risk) you can add this JS to your Content > Design > Configuration > Select area > HTML head >  Scripts and Style Sheets + flush the magento cache:

```
<script>
(function () {
    var cName = 'section_data_ids';

    function getCookie() {   
        var name = cName + "=";
        var cDecoded = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie); //to be careful
        var cArr = cDecoded .split('; ');
        var res;
        cArr.forEach(val => {
          if (val.indexOf(name) === 0) res = val.substring(name.length);
        });
    }
    var res = getCookie();
    while (res && res.indexOf('}lax') != -1) {
        document.cookie = cName + '=';
        res = getCookie();
    }
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a core issue which will be fixed with patch [MC-41359](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360059317752-MC-41359-Magento-patch-missing-settings-SameSite-cookie-param)

You can also add following script on html head in admin section as a workaround to fix this issue temporarily until it is resolved.

```
<script>
    require(['jquery',  'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data', 'mage/cookies'], function ($, customerData) {
        if ($.cookie('section_data_ids') && $.cookie('section_data_ids') !== undefined && $.cookie('section_data_ids').indexOf('lax') !== -1) {
            $.cookie("section_data_ids", null, {
                path: '/',
                domain: window.location.hostname,
                samesite: 'none'
            });
            var uri = window.location.href.split(window.location.hostname)[1];
            uri = uri.split("?")[0] ? uri.split("?")[0] : uri;
            uri = uri.split("#")[0] ? uri.split("#")[0] : uri;
            var lastCharacter = uri.charAt(uri.length - 1);
            if (lastCharacter == '/') {
                uri = uri.substring(0, uri.length - 1);
            }
            $.cookie("section_data_ids", null, {
                path: uri,
                domain: window.location.hostname,
                samesite: 'lax'
            });
            $.cookieStorage.set('section_data_ids', {});
            let sections = ['cart', 'customer'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        }
    });
</script>
```